# How to search the questions which have an accepted answer and the answers which are accepted in 1 search

Tags: discussion, search

I want to list search results for only the questions which have an accepted answer and the answers which are accepted. How can I do this search on SO?

ps. hasaccepted:1 returns only the questions and isaccepted:yes returns only the answers. I want to list both in 1 search.

pseudo search:
"search keywords" hasaccepted:1 OR isaccepted:yes

Comment: `hasaccepted` includes an `is:question` clause, while `isaccepted` includes an `is:answer` clause. You can't have both. You'll have to use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: But normal search already works this way (with the lack of acceptance factor). The normal search returns both questions and answers.

Comment: Yes it does, but as I mentioned, `hasaccepted` only selects questions (and therefore contains an `is:question`-type clause). Similarly, `isaccepted` contains an `is:answer`-type clause. That's why both can't be satisfied together. In a similar sense, the search `stuff is:question is:answer` yields 0 results... _always_ (well, search ignores `is:question` because of `is:answer`, but that's beside the point).

Comment: As Werner said, you can use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to do this. You can write a query to list both the question and the answer in successive columns or the like if you'd like. What the query should read depends on what info you actually want from them.

Comment: Well, I checked Data Explorer. But I didn't understand a thing. If I prepare a search script with Data Explorer, will it appear in the search box of my SO? May I use it from my regular site experience or do I have each time to visit Data Explorer to use it?